# Object Not Passing/Fetch-Post Request/API/NodeJS/Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch, browserify

***Issue***: An object created in JavaScript by input data from a signup form in HTML does not seem to be created.

***Tried:***

1. I checked if I was referencing the entire object with {data} rather just data
2. Searched other online resources to no avail
3. Read again on JavaScript objects to see if I did a simple mistake
4. adding debug strings to give me hints (I will list code below)

***Relevant Code***:

`signup.html`(each snippet is in top to bottom order):

```
<form id="signup-form" name ="signup-form">
    <input class="login-form-field" type="text" name="user" placeholder="username">
    <input class="login-form-field" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <input class="login-form-field" type="password" name="dob" placeholder="date of birth">
    <br>
    <!--<button class="actionButton"></button>-->
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="signupData(this.form)">
</form>
```

```
//last of the markup body with Browserify compiled JavaScript files linked for functionality

<script src="browserify/builds/genKey.js"></script>
<script src="browserify/builds/SignUp.js"></script>
<script  LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function signupData(form) // add to this script
    {
      console.log("signup data is starting");
      var user = form.user.value;
      var email = form.email.value;
      var dob = form.dob.value;

      genSKey();
      genPKey();

      var skey = getSKey();
      
      // var enUser = encryptMes(user);
      // var enEmail = encryptMes(email);
      var endob = encryptMes(dob);

      var data = { name: "LifeNet", members: { user: {profilePic: {}, endob, listeners: {}, listening: {}, friends: {}, requested: {}, blocked:{}, channel: false} } }
      apiPost({data});
      // pass the signup function in here

      // hash the variables and send to celox network
      console.log(JSON.stringify({data}));
      alert (`copy and save your Private Key to somewhere safe: ${skey}`);
    }
</script>
```

`signup.js` (pre-Browserify build):

```
window.apiPost = function({data})

{  
    fetch("https://goldengates.club:3000/api/passData", 
        {
            method: "post",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({data})
        }
    );
}
```

`build.js` (pre-Browserify build):

```
var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");

window.genSKey = function()
{
    var secretKey = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
    var SKey = JSON.stringify(secretKey);

    localStorage.setItem("skey", SKey);
    console.log(SKey);
    alert(`your private key is ${SKey}`)
}
window.genPKey = function()
{
    var skey = localStorage.getItem("skey");

    var SKey = JSON.parse(skey);

    let publicKey;
    if(SKey != null)
    {
        publicKey = eccrypto.getPublic(SKey);
        localStorage.setItem("pkey", JSON.stringify(publicKey));

        return;
    }

    publicKey = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKey);
    localStorage.setItem("pkey", JSON.stringify(publicKey));

    return;
}

window.getPKey = function()
{
    var PKey = localStorage.getItem("pkey");

    var pkey = JSON.parse(PKey);

    return pkey;
}

window.getSKey = function()
{
    var SKey = localStorage.getItem("skey");

    var skey = JSON.parse(SKey);

    return skey;
}

window.encryptMes = function(data)
{
    //for this you need to get the sender's public key to encrypt the message
    if (localStorage.getItem("pkey") === null) 
    {
        if (localStorage.getItem("skey") === null) 
        {
            genSKey();
            genPKey();
        }
    }
    var pkey = getPKey();
    encryptedMes = eccrypto.encrypt(pkey, Buffer.from(data));
    return encryptedMes;
}

window.decryptMes = function(data)
{
    if (localStorage.getItem("skey") === null) 
    {
        genSKey();
    }
    var skey = getSKey();
    decryptedMes = eccrypto.decrypt(SKey, data);
    return decryptedMes.toString();
}

window.encryptData = function()
{
    genSKey();
    genPKey();

    enMes = encryptedMes(/*add a document search for all fields on input form in login*/);
}

window.decryptData = function() {}
```

***Error Code***:

Browser:

1. It runs everything in the signup.html file besides `console.log(JSON.stringify({data}));` in the `signupData(form)` function.
2. Suspicious since the object that was created with user data should have been created and printed to the console.

My API Console:

1. I won't reference the API code since it seems to me that the object is just not being posted to it and that it isn't the problem.
2. 

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at dataPool.setData (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/app/data-Pool.js:64:27)
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/index.js:198:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/main/public_html/Cypher-Network/src/index.js:62:3
```

Any form of help and explanation is greatly appreciated, as I am pretty new to the way JavaScript works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making use of NodeJs, and a framework like express? If yes, then you have to be sure that your backend is able to pass the incoming JSON request. If you use express, you can just use the `express.json()` middleware. Make sure you put it at the top of other middleware or just after the `cors` middleware like so

```
app.use(express.json())
```

That will parse the incoming data from the frontend.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try this, however, the object does not print to console after it has been sent to the api leading me to believe the object is just returning undefined client side either way. Do you think there is an explanation for this?

Comment: yea it looks like I already had it enabled

Comment: ```app.use(bodyParser.json());```